# How can I create a macro to generate this code?

Tags: c++, math, postfix-notation

I wrote a reverse polish notation evaluator that supports many funcions, thus I have a `switch` with many cases like this one:

```
case 'b': {
    if (stack.size() < 1) fail();
    pop(l1, stack);
    l1 = log(l1);
    push(l1, stack);
    break;
}
```

For all the functions that require one argument the template is the same, the only change is the `case` character and the `l1 = ...;`. How can i create a macro that generates this `case`.

Comment: why not write a function instead of a macro?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Alternative: [Take a look at using a `std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to map between a `char` and a function. Then you can `operator[opcode]();` No switch required.

Comment: @jaggedSpire can you suggest something? Or do i need to receive more downvotes? Sorry but I'm not getting this

Comment: @Matteo something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46a16e9de79399ce). I changed some of the function calls to need less boilerplate when using a vector for the `stack` variable because I don't know the full context of your code, but that should give you a decent example. You could *also* write that in a way that didn't capture `stack` by reference and instead write the whole thing as an external function, as well.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks, now I also discovered lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should work:

```
#define THEMACRO(charfunc, functionname) \
  case charfunc: { \
      if (stack.size() < 1) fail(); \
      pop(l1, stack); \
      l1 = functionname(l1); \
      push(l1, stack); \
      break; \
  }
```

Now you can write:

```
THEMACRO('b', log)
THEMACRO('c', someotherfunction)
```

instead of:

```
case 'b': {
    if (stack.size() < 1) fail();
    pop(l1, stack);
    l1 = log(l1);
    push(l1, stack);
    break;
}
case 'c': {
    if (stack.size() < 1) fail();
    pop(l1, stack);
    l1 = someotherfunction(l1);
    push(l1, stack);
    break;
}
```

But it is quite ugly to do this with macros. I'd do this differently.